# How tfileinputexcel works in talend

Tags: talend

I'm trying to load xlsx file into postgresql database.
my excel file contiens 11262 row but after excuting the job i fond 14**** rows and i don't know why? I want only to find my 11262 rows in my table

[here is the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79PQA.png)

[here is my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFaSS.png)

Comment: Aren't there other sheets in your excel ? If it's not already done, uncheck "All sheets" from tFileInputExcel settings, and only provide a single sheet name. And please do not add an answer if you just want to comment. Click "add a comment" for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you didn't check `Stop reading on encountering empty rows`, and that it's reading empty rows from your excel file.

[image]

Please try with checkbox checked.